# Modifying a citation style in CSL editor on Mendeley

Tags: csl

I am currently using the built in citation style 'Journal of the Air & Waste Management Association' as it is the closest to the style that I need. However, the one issue I am having is when it comes to documents with the same first author and year, but different subsequent authors, shown below:

```
 I have a paper by (Elphick, Davies, et al. 2011) and (Elphick, Bergh, et 
 al. 2011).

 What I want is a paper by (Elphick et al. 2011a) and (Elphick et al. 
 2011b).
```

I have a very rudimentary knowledge of computer programming, and have been able to work out some small issues I was having using the CSL editor. However, I have not been able to figure out how to resolve this issue. Is anyone able to help me with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways in CSL 1.0.1 to disambiguate in-text cites that otherwise would look the same. Adding the year-suffixes is the measure of last resort (assuming it's turned on with the "disambiguate-add-year-suffix" attribute on the `<citation>` tag). In your case, you will want to disable the disambiguation method of adding names of additional persons. You can do this by removing the "disambiguate-add-names" from the same tag. "disambiguate-add-year-suffix" needs to be set to "true".

See http://docs.citationstyles.org/en/1.0.1/specification.html#disambiguation for documentation.

If you share your entire `<citation>` tag (with all the attributes and their values) here I can tell you whether you'd need to remove any other disambiguation attributes (the only other one is "disambiguate-add-givenname", but it doesn't look like that's active in your style)

Comment: And to do this in the visual editor, click on "Inline Citation" on the left, then find the `disambiguate-add-names` option at the bottom right and set it to `false`

Comment: Worked perfectly, thanks so much!  Really appreciate the help

Comment: One additional question if you don't mind. now I have it sorted to have the a and b, but how do I redefine which one is a and b? Right now the default is going alphabetically I believe, but I would like 'a' to be the reference I cite first, 'b' to be the one I cite second, and so on. I assume this is also an easy fix, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

Comment: The year-suffix ordering is always based on the order in the bibliography (which, if you don't sort it explicitly, will be sorted by the order in which you cite items in the text).

Comment: I meant the order in which the cited items appear in the text, not the order by which you add the citations to the text.

Comment: I think I understand this now. So if I need it to sort by how I cite it, then remove the sorting from the bibliography. BUT, if I do that, it won't sort my bibliography at all. I need the bibliography to be alphabetical by first author, but if I sort it that way, then I can't assign the 'a' and 'b' in the order I cited. Is there a way to sort first by first author, and then by order cited? So that my bibliography will be in alphabetical order for first author? I read a solution in another forum for zotero, but that coding language is different from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

For those still having issues despite the above, try manually going into the coding section (rather than the visual editor) and manually type disambiguate-add-names=false and this should hopefully resolve any issues if the visual editor isn't working properly. This solved my issue when using Mendeley.